# react-autosuggest with debounce and distinctUntilChanged

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autosuggest, tsx, react-tsx

#### Intent:

I'm trying to achieve an ideal search field that will not make any API calls untill:

1. The debounce time of 350ms has been reached
2. AND until there's a change in the value of the input field.

#### What I've tried so far:

I've used a Subject to track for changes in the input field. Every time there's a change in the input field and `handleSuggestionsFetchRequested` is called, I'm pushing a new value down the `Subject` using `searchString$.next(userInput);`

And in the `useEffect` hook, I'm `pipe`ing the `searchString$` with `debounceTime(350)` and `distinctUntilChanged()`. Something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  searchString$
  .pipe(
    debounceTime(350),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    switchMap(searchString =>
      ajax(`https://api.github.com/search/users?q=${searchString}`)
    ),
    map((networkResponse: any) => networkResponse.response.items)
  )
  .subscribe((suggestions: Array<User>) => setSuggestions(suggestions));
}, [searchString$]);
```

But the API calls are still going everytime there's a change in the userInput.

#### The Issue:

I think the issue is that every time the value of the input field changes, I'm setting the state as well:

```
const handleChange = (
  event: React.ChangeEvent<{}>,
  { newValue }: Autosuggest.ChangeEvent
) => {
  setUserInput(newValue);
};
```

This is causing the Component to re-render and calling the useEffect, which is eventually making the API call again and again.

I could be wrong.

#### How to replicate:

> I've created a [**Sample Code Sandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-autosuggest-github-search-mnco4) that replicates the issue.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the comments from [yurzui](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5485167/yurzui) on my [tweet](https://twitter.com/SiddAjmera/status/1143708202153889792), I was able to figure out the reason for the issue.

I was creating a new `Subject` on every reconciliation as the line:

```
const searchString$: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();
```

was right inside my component function.

I moved it out and it was working like a charm.

NOTE: As suggested by [yurzui](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5485167/yurzui), don't forget to catch errors in the ajax call otherwise the `Subject` will die.

I've updated the Code Sandbox Sample, just in case somebody needs to refer to it.